# how to solve an installation error on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I tried to install panda using pip and it was unsuccessful and I got an error saying "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor..
I uninstalled and installed two other versions of python and I got the same error whenever I want to install modules..Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you post what commend did you use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Python and remove all Python directories from the **"User PATH"** [Environment Variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) (And if there are only Python directories, then delete the variable):

[image]

Then reinstall Python, and don't forget to check **"Add Python to PATH" (Important)**.